# Replace Multiple Documents in Cosmos DB using Store procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I had Fetch Multiple Documents. I had cast all the Documents to there respective data Models. After Updating properties of each Document, I need to save all the documents from a stored procedure. 
I have Read the Documentation of [stored procedure Collection](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html) in this the Method **replaceDocument(documentLink, document, optionsopt, callbackopt)** Required documentLink which I can not find after Casting.

I have tried this function but it did not work

```
function bulkReplace(docs) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var count = 0;

if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

var docsLength = docs.length;
if (docsLength == 0) {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    return;
}

tryCreate(docs[count], callback);

function tryCreate(doc, callback) {
    var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(doc._self, doc, callback);

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
}

   function callback(err, doc, options) {
    if (err) throw err;

    count++;

    if (count >= docsLength) {

        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    } else {

        tryCreate(docs[count], callback);
    }
}
}
```

Exception details:

> "Unable to Process Request","errorDetails":"The server encountered a
>   problem while processing your request, please try again
>   "technicalReason":"Type:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException
>   Source:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client Message:Message:
>   {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing Javascript.
>   Exception = Error: Invalid document link: \"undefined\".\r\nStack
>   trace: Error: Invalid document link: \"undefined\".\n at
>   validateDocumentLink
>   (bulkReplace.js:349:21)\natreplaceDocument(bulkReplace.js:780:17)\n
>   at tryCreate (bulkReplace.js:45:9)

Comment: Any exception or error log you saw?

Comment: errorDescription":"Unable to Process Request","errorDetails":"The server encountered a problem while processing your request, please try again "technicalReason":"Type:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException Source:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client Message:Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid document link: \"undefined\".\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid document link: \"undefined\".\\n at validateDocumentLink (bulkReplace.js:349:21)\\natreplaceDocument(bulkReplace.js:780:17)\\n at tryCreate (bulkReplace.js:45:9)   @JayGong

Comment: It Work when i fetch the Document within store procedure and Provide the fetch Document link. but it incerase one call to database within store procedure.

Comment: Hi, I already edit your error message in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code on my side and it works.

As we know, documents in azure document db has a few auto-generate fields including `"_self"`. You do not need to make another query in stored procedure.You just need to ensure the documents in `docs` param you import contain the right `"_self"` field, otherwise the `invalid document link` exception occurs.

For example :

```
var doc = { "id": "2", 
            "name" : "ccc",
            "_self": "dbs/duUuAA==/colls/duUuAPfBbAA=/docs/duUuAPfBbAAzAQAAAAAAAA==/",
}
```

I suggest you use `console.log()` to print the `doc._self` in your code to check the value of it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: is that means i need to make another property name "_self" in each model?  @jayGong

Comment: @SatyaraySingh Yes,it need to be set into the models. I think the data source you process should be retrieved from  cosmos db, "_self" properties should be with the data source right?

Comment: @SatyaraySingh Hi,if my answer helps you , you could mark it for others' reference on the forum.Thx!

Comment: it Works if we add  "_self" properties to model and use the same properties in stored procedure while calling replaceDocument () method. @jay Gong